# Working of static variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internals

A bit of confusion on how `static` works in javascript.

```
function StaticExample() {}

StaticExample.staticProp = "Hello"

console.log(StaticExample.staticProp) // "Hello"
```

Here I have created a `function` and then created a static variable `staticProp` (not if we can call it static though). This adds the field `staticProp` to the `constructor` field on `StaticExample`'s `prototype`

Question 1: Is there a specific reason to this behaviour(field getting added to the constructor property)?

Now the `constructor` is rewritten as below.

```
StaticExample.prototype.constructor = {}

console.log(StaticExample.staticProp) // "Hello"
```

Even after that, when I tried to access `StaticExample.staticProp`, it provides the correct value of `Hello`

Question 2: From where the `staticProp` fetched, even when the `constructor` where it was initially added is overwritten.

Comment: You're somewhat overthinking this. You assign to `StaticExample.staticProp`, so you can access `StaticExample.staticProp`. It's right there where you assigned it to.

Comment: Static variables refer to a variable that has been allocated "statically", which means it lasts for the entirety of the program. They contrast with automatic variable that are stack-allocated, and objects, which are stored in heap memory. These are not really terms that you encounter much in JavaScript programming because you don't manually mess with memory and how things are allocated or deallocated. Is this what you mean when you say static, or are you referring to a static property of a class, which can be called without instantiating a new instance from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StaticExample` is an object. A function object, but an object nonetheless.
You assign a new property to it: `StaticExample.staticProp = "Hello"`.

`StaticExample` also happens to have a property `prototype`.
The property `StaticExample.prototype.constructor` points to `StaticExample`.

Now, you can obviously access `StaticExample.staticProp`, because it's simply a property of an object that you assigned.

You can also replace the value of `StaticExample.prototype.constructor` with something else; now `StaticExample.prototype.constructor` doesn't point to `StaticExample` anymore. But `StaticExample` is still `StaticExample` and it still has the property `staticProp` that you created on it. You didn't replace the `StaticExample` object in any way. What you did replace was `StaticExample.prototype.constructor`, which is a different property of a different object.